# What is 'gem activerecord-redshift-adapter' about?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, amazon-redshift, rails-activerecord

I was exploring Ruby gem 'activerecord-redshift-adapter' but I am not getting is what is about.

This gem includes  'gem pg'. Why? Redshift is a database. Why does use/includes pg then? What is the need?

Also redshift says it does not support postgresql database datatypes like : JSON, UUID etc. But some module do provide functions/methods for these.

Comment: Your question is not really clear. That gem is an ActiveRecord adapter which makes Rails able to read/write data in a Redshift database. Please edit your question to add some more context regarding your question.

Comment: I am sorry. I am myself very confused. I have edited my question. I hope I am able to explain my question bit better now. And Thank you very much.

Comment: It's much better :). Let me post an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `activerecord-redshift-adapter` gem is a database adapter for ActiveRecord, which is part of Rails.

From [the Redshift Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Redshift):

> Amazon Redshift is based on an older version of PostgreSQL 8.0.2, and Redshift has made changes to that version.

So that gem uses the `pg` gem that implements all the basic PostgreSQL features, and then the gem adds the Redshift features so that all in all, Rails can read/write data in a Redshift database plus it can use all the Redshift objects and features.

Comment: Does it support some features or data types which redshift does not?

Comment: No, as Redshift only adds stuff to PostgreSQL, the gem covers all the PostgreSQL features, and the Redshift one, so it should fit exactly for Redshift.